# Error archiving a CocoaPods dependency for release to App Store

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following library in my mobile app to provide users with an onboarding tutorial: [ephread/Instructions](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions).

Everything was working fine until I recently updated XCode to version 10. After updating, I made sure to update all dependencies to using versions that support Swift 4.2

In the case of the library in question, the changes aren't available in a Cocoapods release yet so I used a specific branch as suggested by the library author as follows:

```
pod 'Instructions', :git => 'https://github.com/ephread/Instructions.git', :branch => 'swift4'
```

Everything works fine when I compile and run in Debug. However, when I try to an archive build for release, I get the following error (I've only included what I think is relevant here for brevity).

```
<unknown>:0: error: fatal error encountered while reading from module 'Instructions'; please file a bug report with your project and the crash log
<unknown>:0: note: compiling as Swift 4.1.50, with 'Instructions' built as Swift 4.2.1 (this is supported but may expose additional compiler issues)

*** DESERIALIZATION FAILURE (please include this section in any bug report) ***
could not deserialize type for '_': could not deserialize type for 'windowLevel': declaration is not a nominal type
Cross-reference to module 'UIKit'
... Level

0  swift                    0x000000011114159a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000111140d4e SignalHandler(int) + 302

...

3.  While deserializing SIL vtable for 'OverlayManager' in module 'Instructions'
error: Abort trap: 6
```

Is this something that I'm doing wrong or is it a problem with the library that I can't fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with libs that were not updated to Swift4.2

adding this to the Podfile fixed the issue for me

```
swift4Targets = ['POD NAME']
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if swift4Targets.include? target.name
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
                else
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding this and unfortunately it didn't work in my case.